# Как добавить иконку в MessageBox?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть класс, в котором описан метод:

```
 public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr handle, 
     string text, string title, uint type);
```

Я вызываю его с указанными параметрами в обработчике:

```
IntPtr handle = this.Handle;
string text = "text";
string title = "title";
uint type = 4;
WinAPIClass.MessageBox(handle, text, title, type);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить иконку `MB_ICONQUESTION`?

Comment: [MessageBox function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) ?

Answer (score 2):

Правильный ответ - с помощью апи MessageBox - **никак**.

Можно попробывать два варианта.

1.Хакерский :)

---

1. получить HWND окна MessageBox'а,
2. получить HWND под-окна где распологается родная иконка (неважно какая),
3. загрузить свой битмап (из ресурса или файла),
4. с помощью SendMessage запульть туда свой битмап (в окно из пункта 2).

2.Написать самому MessageBox с нуля

---

Это не так сложно как кажется, например на основе элемента Dialog.

Есть и сторонние наработки, приведу несколько ссылок:

> TaskDialogIndirect создает, отображает и управляет диалоговым окном
>   задачи. Диалог задач содержит определенные приложением значки,
>   сообщения, заголовок, флажок проверки, ссылки на команды, кнопки и
>   переключатели.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-taskdialogindirect

> Использование хуков Windows для улучшения MessageBox в .NET

- http://web.archive.org/web/20150519135315/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188920.aspx

> CustomMessageBox - работает точно так же, как обычный класс сообщений. Автор [Brian Graham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711416/brian-graham)

- https://pastebin.com/m8evBmZi
- https://pastebin.com/CRXjeUFN
- https://pastebin.com/jawHZDzY

> Имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону фреймворка Metro .NET, там много элементов с расширенным функционалом, в том числе и MessageBox (Dialog)

- https://mahapps.com/controls/dialogs.html