# Как добавить собственные кнопки в MessageBoxButtons?

Tags: c#

Я могу использовать только кнопки:

```
AbortRetryIgnore
OK
OKCancel
RetryCancel
YesNo
YesNoCancel
```

А я хочу использовать свои кнопки, после нажатия которых, будет, например, открываться 2ой MessageBox. Возможно ли обойтись без использования Windows Form?

Сейчас я имею следующее:

```
MessageBox.Show("Выберите метод шифрования!\r\n"
                + "Нажмите на кнопку \"random\"\r\n" 
                + "Используйте \"Encrypt\" для шифрования\r\n" 
                + "Используйте \"Decrypt\"для дешифрования\r\n", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            if (MessageBoxButtons.OK == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(""); //здесь должно быть все переведено на англ
            }
```

Я не хочу нажимать на кнопку OK, а хочу нажимать на кнопку "перевести", например.

Comment: Вы хотите свою форму, но не используя формы?

Comment: @tym32167 я дополнил вопрос

Comment: Мессаджбокс поддерживает только те кнопки, что указаны в его документации. Если вам нужна своя кнопка, то придется сделать свою форму. Кстати, вот это `if (MessageBoxButtons.OK == 0)` - какая то ерунда, вам надо результат показа бокса проверять, а не то, что вы делаете.

Comment: Нужно использовать "Message box hooks" через "WinAPI" https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/hooks

Comment: @tym32167, а что не так с 'if (MessageBoxButtons.OK == 0)'? после нажатия кнопки, открывается новый MessageBox, как я и хотел

Comment: Проблема в том, что это условие всегда "Верно" т.к. вы сравниваете элемент перечисления(хеш кнопки "ОК") с 0. Это условие работает не так как вы хотите. Попробуйте закрыть диалог нажатием на крестик. Это будет работать так же как и нажатие на ОК.

Comment: Из того же разряда что про кнопки :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/967969/Как-добавить-иконку-в-messagebox/968047#968047 - там есть ссылки как решить кастомно окно сообщений

Comment: @NewView Никогда не писал класс с нуля(

Comment: Ну когда то надо начинать писать с нуля, посмотрите, есть готовые реализации, начните с них. Типовая логическая ошибка, что вместо создания кастомного диалога, пытаются приделать туда MessageBox.